# ¿Cómo identificar un hilo (thread) del resto en c#?

Tags: c#, hilos

Tengo un código en el que inicializo un arreglo de hilos y quiero identificar cada hilo, tenía la idea de cada que se crea un hilo, mandar un parámetro que me permita identificarlos

```
for (int no_abe = 0; no_abe < abeja.Length; no_abe++)
            {
                abeja[no_abe] = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() => Abejas(no_abe)));
            }
```

Este es el método que llamo al momento de crear el hilo

```
public void Abejas(int no_abe)
        {
            Random rand = new Random();
            int noAbeja = no_abe;
            int produce;
            while (true)
            {
                produce = rand.Next(1, 4);
                Console.WriteLine("Abeja {0}", no_abe);
                Console.WriteLine("Prod {0}", produce);
                tarro += produce;
            }
        }
```

Al momento de imprimir el numero de la abeja (hilo), siempre me muestra el numero del ultimo hilo. ¿Cómo puedo identificar a cada hilo?

Comment: Recuerda llamar la función `Start` del hilo o no comenzará a ejecutarse solo. Puedes cambiar la propiedad `Name` del hilo para identificarlo y usar `Thread.CurrentThread` para obtener el hilo que está corriendo el código. https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread

Comment: Te recomiendo leer sobre ConcurrentBag y Parallel.ForEach, con este par, podrías tener un acercamiento interesante a Threads. Saludos :D

Comment: Este problema es re interesante, y tiene que ver con la definicion del lenguaje.. en un rato, si puedo, armo una respuesta.. TLDR dentro del for pone int param = i y pasa param y no va a pasar mas...

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 0):

Esto es un problema conocido como [Closure](https://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Closures), excelentemente explicado por Jon Skeet en su articulo.

Lo que esta pasando aca, es que la definicion del lenguaje no crea una variable y la pasa a cada thread, si no que usa para todos los threads la misma variable, porque lo que pasa es un puntero.

La funcion lambda, cuando llega a ejecutarse, ya ve la variable con su ultimo valor.

Esto pasa con los while, con los for e inclusive con for each.. pero esto ultimo se "arreglo" luego de c# 5.

Para evitar esto, hay que crear una variable local, para que en cada vuelta se vaya tomando una nueva. en tu codigo, deberia quedar asi:

```
for (int no_abe = 0; no_abe < abeja.Length; no_abe++)
{
    int param = no_abe;
    abeja[no_abe] = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() => Abejas(param)));
}
```